# How to get the current `node` name and `cluster` name in JBoss?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

While handling a servlet request in JBoss 7, I need to get the current `node` name and `cluster` name, how do I get it ?

Comment: Which application server and why do you need it ? What have you tried so far ?

Comment: we r working in jboss 7 .we got server and client ip but unable to get cluster and node name?

Comment: You want the cluster and node name of the current server when handling a servlet request ?

Answer (score 11):

you might be looking for system property

```
jboss.node.name
```

that property holds the name of the node inside cluster.

also you can get name of the server by reading property

```
jboss.server.name
```

for cluster name I don't know what you mean, pre-AS7 that was partition name, that is now gone, so you might be looking for "cache name".